# SPARQL: Exclude datatype uri from query result

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I am trying to learn SPARQL queries on Protege and I have added some individuals to query on the Movie ontology found at :
[Movie Ontology](https://github.com/ontop/ontop/wiki/Example_MovieOntology)

I have following simple sparql query:

```
Query 1: Get all movies and actors having rating more than 7.0 

PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX mov: <http://www.movieontology.org/2009/10/01/movieontology.owl#>

SELECT ?subject ?actors ?rating
    WHERE { 
        ?subject a mov:Movie;
             mov:hasActor ?actors;
            mov:imdbrating ?rating.
        Filter(?rating > "7.0"^^xsd:double)
     }
```

And I am getting the result as expected:

[image: Result]

The problem is that I dont need the ^^xsd:double uri in the rating column !! 
How do I get rid of the uri " ^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double ". 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str` to get the lexical part

`SELECT ?subject ?actors (str(?rating) AS ?r)`